# Hiding ActionBar on touching surface

Tags: java, android, touch, android-actionbar

I'm writing a very simple android app. When the user touches the surface and moves their finger around, pictures are drawn below their fingers. When their finger is raised, this stops.

I want the action bar to hide when the finger is down and reappear when it is raised.

The ActionBar is overlayed. I thought using ActionBar.hide() and .show() in my view's onTouchEvent would work fine, but I've hit some problems.

I've tried a few things. First I tried passing the ActionBar created in the Activity into the view, but this didn't work as the view has to be created before the ActionBar is "got", so I would just be passing in a null value.

I then tried to make a static ActionBar which I can call from my view, but then I get this error: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.”

Anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at one of the examples that is part of the jfeinstein10's [Sliding Menu library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

In it, in the [BirdActivity.java](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/slidingmenu/example/fragments/BirdActivity.java), you will see how the `ActionBar` is shown and hidden after 2 seconds. You will naturally have to adapt the code yourself. But this should get you started:

Excerpt of the code from **Line No. 53 - 58**:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        hideActionBarDelayed(mHandler);
    }
});
```

The `hideActionBarDelayed()` from **Line No. 80 - 86**:

```
private void hideActionBarDelayed(Handler handler) {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

**UPDATE**

For the lack of code, most of the problem has been assumed. It may be wrong simply for the lack of data from the OP. That being said, if sorting out the *"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."* problem will fix it, perhaps this may do it for you:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
            // RUN YOUR CODE TO HIDE / SHOW THE ACTIONBAR HERE      
    }
}; YOUR_ACTIVITY.this.runOnUiThread(run); // REPLACE WITH getActivity().runOnUiThread(run); IF THIS IS A FRAGMENT
```

**NOTE:** In the example, the activity in question uses [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and extends `SherlockActivity` and therefore, the use of `getSupportActionBar()`. If you are not using ABS, you will have to use `getActionBar()` instead of the former.